# Optional keys in different circumstances

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in Typescript to optionally require keys in different circumstances?

For example

```
interface IDog {
  name: string;
  weight: number;
}

class Retriever implements IDog {
  name = "Dug";
  weight = 70;

  public updateAttribute(props: IDog) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Let's say `updateAttribute` can get either objects: `{ name: "" }`, `{ weight: 500 }`, `{ name: "", weight: 30 }`, `{}`. Right now, I would either have to add `?` to every attribute in IDog, or add `?` to `(props?: IDog)`. Both aren't great solutions, because I want Retriever to require the attributes, and I want each attribute to be option in `updateAttribute`.

Is there a way to update `updateAttribute` to allow for any permutation of IDog, but still make all attributes required for the class?

Comment: Retriever implements `IDog` by definition, the `implements` clause is superfluous. Anyway, you can make the properties required and take a `Partial<IDog>` as a parameter.

Comment: Typo from writing the example off the cuff. `Partial<>` is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks for the response!

Comment: @Aluan Haddad you should put that in as an answer as it should be the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the `Partial` type. The partial type is a generic type which makes all the fields of it's argument optional. So for your example:

```
interface IDog {
  name: string;
  weight: number;
}

class Retriever implements IDog {
  name = "Dug";
  weight = 70;

  public updateAttribute(props: Partial<IDog>) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Should work. For clarity, `Partial<IDog>` will be equivalent to the type:

```
Partial<IDog> = {
  name?: string;
  weight?: number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CRice's answer is correct. Using the `Partial<T>` type is the correct and idomatic approach.

However, it is worth noting that, as TypeScript is a structurally typed language, the `implements` clause is a formality that does not affect type compatibility. 
This means that for an interface

```
interface IDog {
  name: string;
  weight: number;
}
```

the following are equivalent:

```
class Dog implements IDog {
  name = "Fred";
  weight = 100;
}
```

and

```
class Dog {
  name = "Fred";
  weight = 100;
}
```

both are implementations of `IDog` *by definition*.

It is further worth noting that, by implication,  `T` is an implementation of  `Partial<T>`.

Hence you could write the following as well (`--strictNullChecks` assumed)

```
class Retriever {
  name = "Dug";
  weight = 70;

  updateAttribute(props: Partial<this>) {
    Object.assign(this, props);  
  }
}
```

We can further generalize this in an interesting way by making `updateAttribute` return `this`.

```
updateAttribute<U extends  Partial<this>>(props: U): this & U {
  return Object.assign(this, props);  
}
```

which allows the following

```
class Retriever {
  name = "Dug";
  weight = 70;
  age?: number;

  updateAttribute<U extends Partial<this>>(props: U): this & U {
    return Object.assign(this, props);
  }
}

new Retriever().age.toFixed(); // error possibly undefined.
new Retriever().updateAttribute({age: 30}).age.toFixed(); // OK
```